# Smooth Path traversing in C#

Tags: c#, path, spline

I'm looking for a C# implementation of a Spline, 
not to draw it, but to traverse it.
Basically I have a 2D game and I want an object to move on a predefined path.

Any ideas how to implement this ?
Thanks,
SW

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some equations on how to interpolate splines:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

This may also help: [Calculate a bezier spline to get from point to point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879179/calculate-a-bezier-spline-to-get-from-point-to-point)

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do this for a game years ago, I implemented a form of [parametric spline curve](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/AndysSplineTutorial/Parametrics.html) that was simple to build and required little in the way of CPU resources.  What I built is similar to what's in the linked article.  One really nice thing about this type of spline is that the math is not at all advanced.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the C source code for my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Numerical Recipes, and netlib.org.